# the conversion issue for using img_as_float

Tags: scipy, scikit-image

There is a multi-dimensional array to store images, e.g., imgs is of shape `(512,512)`. Its `dtype` is `float64` while the maximum value is `255.0`, the minimum value is `0.0`.   I am trying to scale it to `0 and 1.`

I used `new_imgs = img_as_float(imgs)`. However, I found that the maximum value of `new_imgs` is still `255.0`. In other words, it fails to scale the pixel values to `1`.  This seems to be contradict to what API documents describe:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `img_as_float` does not modify the numbers if the image is already given in a float type, see [issue here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1737).

Instead you could divide the values in the image by 255.0, to get them from [0; 255] to lie between [0; 1].

Comment: Either you could try to case the image to dtype=np.uint first.